# Different 'connection types' between components

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, parallel, series, graph

Is there a name for the different types of connections between components? For example in the following:

[image]

- Point A is connected between two components -- a battery and resistor -- and so is in series.
- Point B is connected between > two components, and so is in parallel.
- Point C is connected between three components (though I believe "Ground" is not really a component so it disappears into the negative terminal?).

Are there formal names for the types of 'junctions' or what they'd be called to differentiate the connection points (nodes/vertices in graph theory).

Comment: Connection points are just that - connection points. They have no meaning by themselves, only by the specific circuits they create.  The "series" and "parallel" notations applicable to these circuits not to the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it is worth, I have used the textbook "Circuit Analysis and Design" by
Ulaby, Maharbiz, and Furse. This book uses the following definitions:

> **Node**: An electrical connection between two or more elements.
>
> **Ordinary node**: An electrical connection node that connects to only two elements.
>
> **Extraordinary node**: An electrical connection node that connects to three or more elements.

Comment: That definition makes more sense without drawing false equivalencies.

Comment: @Elliot -- thanks, that seems simple enough. Are those terms used frequently (ordinary, extraordinary), or not really?

Comment: @Elliot -- what is the difference between a "junction" and a "node" ?

Comment: Here's another link: https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-a-node-and-junction-in-electrical-circuits.

Comment: I've never seen these terms used anywhere else. I don't think there is any standard distinction between a "junction" and a "node" when discussing schematics.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the best part of all this is a comment by @DKNguyen: "but in the end, is it useful?"

You can call those nodes any way you want... and in the end it will give you **exactly zero** useful information. Here is why:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTBYUf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, I haven't changed anything at point B. It is still "3-way" or "extraordinary" or "node with branch" or whatever else you choose to call it.
But the whole function of the circuit changed. That is because individual points do not matter by themselves, only by the closed circuits they create *en masse*.

Answer (score 2):

No, because a single node does not define whether something is in parallel or series, and even the terms parallel and series quickly lose meaning as you get more components.

Look at your example B closely enough and you will see that your "definition" is downright fuzzy.

Your components are unlabelled which makes talking about it unwieldly. Resistors from left to right I will call X, Y, and Z.

- Y and Z are in parallel with each other.
- The Y/Z combination is in series with X.

  Does >2 connections to a node really mean parallel? and not series? Does it always mean both? What if one of the vertical resistors had a capacitor in series with it? What happens to Node B? I don't know. That's because your definition isn't rigourous enough to be useful.

Comment: DKNguyen -- right, but are there ways to describe the properties of a node -- for example, whether it contains a possible branch or not.

Comment: You can call a Node is a Test Point TP#,  for testability purposes.  Gnd is wherever you want to call 0V at any/all frequencies incl DC. It is just a logical point, and not necessarily accurate due to geometry and EMI

Comment: @David542 See updated answer.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks, I see. I suppose one fuzzy way to put it would be a node with more than two connections would imply that there is a parallel/branch coming out of it (though as you've pointed out there could also be a series coming out of it as well).

Comment: @David542 Yeah, I guess >2 connections to a node always mean series AND parallel connection somewhere...but it's just not useful to define that. You can define and classify things all sorts of ways (including arbitrary ways), but in the end, is it useful?